# How to serve images without making folder directly accessible

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, image

For the last couple years i made websites, and i know how to set (background) images on different objects.
I always linked directly to the images as you can find in all tutorials:
`background-image: url("myfolder/images/background_blue.png");`

In my my most recent project, people can upload their (for example profile) images themself. I do this via a jquery ajax call, converted to base64 where PHP takes the server-side, converts it back and stores it as a unique name e.g. **123456.png.** Later the background is set via jquery. For example
`background-image: url("accounts/profileimage/123456.png");`

But i see that this can be dangerous because people can guess that the next image will be 785256.png for example. So when they view the sourcecode they see the full url http://www.mywebsite.com/accounts/profileimage/123456.png and can browse directly to this.

How can i serve these images in a safe way that people cant directly browse to it. Do i have to serve them via base64 or something? Or let PHP serve them so that people cant access the url directly?

What is a best practice in this case or something to search for? A little guidance would be great. Thank you.

I tried searching google for this question, and some people say you have to use base64, but others say this is a giant waste of performance. Its quite hard to search for this exact question and get good results.

Comment: Don't use an incremental integer to build the file name, use a [v4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Users will still be able to directly request the URL, but they'll be unguessable.

Comment: There won't be a perfect solution for this. You can use htaccess to block access when no referrer is passed but many browsers/users/software disables that field so that would affect legit users. You can always use some sort of unique file name, using PHP uniqid (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) this is probably the best option. The file names can still be technically guessed but for your purposes, it will suffice.

Comment: Are you worried about the possible guessing of urls or people being able to browse to an image? It sounds like both from some of the wording in the question. If it’s the first, you could create a file name based on an encryption of the username perhaps.

Comment: @ A.Haworth, 

Its that people can directly browse towards the image-file. The folder profileimages must be accasbile otherwise the client cant reach  (download) the image? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Authorizing static resource requests

As you haven't provided any code, I'll stick to providing a more conceptual answer. In a lot of servers, when a request for a static resource is received, the server will simply reply with the contents of that static resource. If you don't want everyone to be able to access a resource, you can require that a user be authenticated and authorized prior to receiving it. This is common for almost any resource, static or not (e.g. access to a user's dynamic sensitive data requires authentication).

If you're using some sort of prewritten middleware for your static resources, as most people are, you'll either want

- to write your own static resource middleware that integrates with your authentication mechanism to deny unauthenticated/unauthorized requests
- or write a middleware that comes just before the static resource middleware and denies the unauthenticated/unauthorized requests before they reach the static resource middleware.

#### Static resource requests middleware

When writing the middleware, you'll need to have some mechanism of determining who the resource belongs to. In a relational database, you could keep a table that maps the static resource's identifier to the user or group/role that has access to it. Then you could check if the requester matches what's in the table. With a document based database, you could either co-locate the information about who has access to the static resource with those who have access or do something similar to the relational database solution.

This might look like the following:

- client `POST /login?username=admin&password=secret` -> server

  - server authenticates user and creates an authentication token
  - server `Cookie: authtoken=supersecrettokenforauthentication` -> client
- client `GET /profile` -> server

  - server checks if user is authenticated and retrieves user profile data
  - server `{ name: "Admin", photo: "/profile-photos/90c4c276-c8ff-4d02-8b2e-5cc47f81a3cf.png" }` -> client
- client `GET /profile-photos/90c4c276-c8ff-4d02-8b2e-5cc47f81a3cf.png`

  - server gets username associated with the profile photo: `admin`
  - server checks `authtoken` against that user, which succeeds
  - server PNG data -> client
- malicious client `GET /profile-photos/not-supposed-to-access-me.png`

  - server gets username associated with the profile photo: `janedoe`
  - server checks `authtoken` against that user, which fails
  - server `401 Unauthorized` -> client

### Dynamically serving static resources

Another option you have is to not serve the resource based on its static filename. Instead, you could associate the static resource with a dynamic resource (e.g. the user, a post, etc.). This might look like requesting a resource like `/users/${user-id}/profile-picture` or `/posts/${post-id}/images/${index}`. In this solution, the authentication would already be tied to whatever dynamic resource the static resource is tied to given that the real filename of the resource is only held in the dynamic resource (e.g. user or post). Those who don't have access to that dynamic resource would then get denied access.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My site doesnt have any kind of authentication, it isnt necessary. When people leave the site, all data will be removed again. But what i do have is a resourceid for each and every user, tied to the sockets. This ID is also used in the database as primary key.
Serving the content dynamically and usingn this id (which is hidden for the user itself) is a perfect user-id in your solution. When the request isnt from this resourceid, the content isnt served at all. This was the kind of answer / direction i was looking for.

Thank you.